# Import module from different folders

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I want to import different folders as modules.

My folder structure is like this:

```
/project
    /movies
        get_genres.py
    /mysql
        /movies
            insert_genres.py
```

In my `insert_genres.py` script I import:

```
import movies.get_genres as moviegenres

def main():
    for key, value in moviegenres.items():
        print(key)

main()
```

And i get error like this:

```
import movies.get_genres as moviegenres
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'movies'
```

I opened empty `__init__.py` file in each folder but it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/279237/4450498 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/72852/4450498

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score -1):

Your folder structure is not being recognised as a package because you don't have any **init**.py files in your directories. The **init**.py files are required to let Python know that the directory should be treated as a package.

Folder structure should look like this:

```
/project
    /movies
        __init__.py
        get_genres.py
    /mysql
        /movies
            __init__.py
            insert_genres.py
```

Create empty **init**.py files in both the /movies and /mysql/movies folders.

Update the sys.path in your insert_genres.py file to include the parent directory, so that Python can find the movies package:

```
import sys
import os

# Add the parent directory to the Python path
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

import movies.get_genres as moviegenres

def main():
    for key, value in moviegenres.items():
        print(key)

main()
```

Comment: I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'movies.get_genres'` error now.